# How do I hide and show individual tables based on button selction?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide, css-tables

So, I am pretty new to Js and I don't really know what I am doing here. I have three  links that hide/show 3 different tables. I have gotten them to work but, what I want ideally, is that when the various  links are clicked, they should hide the other two tables that are not selected. So, I only in theory have the table that has been selected displaying. I'm not sure how to do this. Would be eternally grateful if someone could point me in the right direction here. I have included my code here.

```js
function toggleTable1() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("loginTable1");
  var hide = elem.style.display == "none";
  if (hide) {
    elem.style.display = "table";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function toggleTable2() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("loginTable2");
  var hide = elem.style.display == "none";
  if (hide) {
    elem.style.display = "table";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function toggleTable3() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("loginTable3");
  var hide = elem.style.display == "none";
  if (hide) {
    elem.style.display = "table";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<a id="loginLink1" onclick="toggleTable1();" href="#">Login1</a>
<a id="loginLink2" onclick="toggleTable2();" href="#">Login2</a>
<a id="loginLink3" onclick="toggleTable3();" href="#">Login3</a>
<table id="loginTable1" width="1139" height="327" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Individuals<span style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;"></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent A</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/1.png" width="750" height="33" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent B</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent C</span> </th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/2.png" width="750" height="33" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent D</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent E</span></span>
      </th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/3.png" width="750" height="33" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent F</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="loginTable2" width="1139" height="327" border="0" style="display: none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Branches<span style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;"></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Sandton City Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/1@2x.jpg" width="750" height="33" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: ##005c61; font-size: 12px;">Mall of Africa Branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Bank City Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/2@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">West Street branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Springs Mall Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/3@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="text-decoration-color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Westgate Mall Branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="loginTable3" width="1139" height="327" border="0" style="display: none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Region</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Inland</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/region/1@2x.jpg" width="750" height="34" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: ##005c61; font-size: 12px;">Eastern Cape</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Gauteng North</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/region/2@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Gauteng South</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Soshanguve</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/3@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="text-decoration-color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Ga-Rankuwa</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: > Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Please fix this in your snippet.

Comment: Try using same class name for all three tables, run a loop hide all and then call your function to show the selected table

Comment: I removed your <script> tags from your snippet

Comment: simple get the other two tables on all the three functions and then force `display: none` on them so they'll close anyways

Comment: Please try using JQuery `toggle()` method

    `$("button1").click(function(){
        $("loginTable1").toggle();
      });`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
function toggleTable1() {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById("loginTable1");
  var elem2 = document.getElementById("loginTable2");
  var elem3 = document.getElementById("loginTable3");
  var hide = elem.style.display === "none";
  if (hide) {
    elem1.style.display = "table";
    elem2.style.display = "none";
    elem3.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    elem1.style.display = "none";
    elem2.style.display = "none";
    elem3.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide all tables first then show the table you want to show.
I modified some of the code to make it more dynamic.

**Not much, but honest work**.

```js
function hideAllTables(){
  document.getElementById("loginTable1").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("loginTable2").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("loginTable3").style.display = 'none';

}
function toggleTable(tableId){
    hideAllTables();
    var elem = document.getElementById(tableId)
    elem.style.display = "table";
      
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    
    <a id="loginLink1" onclick="toggleTable('loginTable1');" href="#">Login1</a>
    <a id="loginLink2" onclick="toggleTable('loginTable2');" href="#">Login2</a>
    <a id="loginLink3" onclick="toggleTable('loginTable3');" href="#">Login3</a>
<table id="loginTable1" width="1139" height="327" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Individuals<span style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;"></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent A</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/1.png" width="750" height="33" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent B</span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent C</span>      </th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/2.png" width="750" height="33" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent D</span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent E</span></span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/3.png" width="750" height="33" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent F</span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    
    <table id="loginTable2" width="1139" height="327" border="0" style="display: none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Branches<span style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;"></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Sandton City Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/1@2x.jpg" width="750" height="33" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: ##005c61; font-size: 12px;">Mall of Africa Branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Bank City Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/2@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">West Street branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Springs Mall Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/3@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="text-decoration-color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Westgate Mall Branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    
    <table id="loginTable3" width="1139" height="327" border="0" style="display: none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Region</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Inland</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/region/1@2x.jpg" width="750" height="34" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: ##005c61; font-size: 12px;">Eastern Cape</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Gauteng North</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/region/2@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Gauteng South</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Soshanguve</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/3@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt=""/></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="text-decoration-color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Ga-Rankuwa</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate and use a data-attribute

I also added a class hide that can be toggled

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
    const tgt = e.target;
    [...this.querySelectorAll("a")]
    .forEach(link => {
      document.getElementById(link.dataset.id).classList.add("hide")
    });
    document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.id).classList.remove("hide")
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <a data-id="loginTable1" href="#">Login1</a>
  <a data-id="loginTable2" href="#">Login2</a>
  <a data-id="loginTable3" href="#">Login3</a>
</nav>
<table id="loginTable1" width="1139" height="327" border="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Individuals<span style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<table id="loginTable2" width="1139" height="327" border="0" class="hide">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Branches<span style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<table id="loginTable3" width="1139" height="327" border="0" class="hide">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Region</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this the exact solution for you question**

**- *You can add more table and button to "tableList" array***

```js
var tableList = [
        {
            button: document.querySelector('#loginLink1'),
            table: document.querySelector('#loginTable1')
        },
        {
            button: document.querySelector('#loginLink2'),
            table: document.querySelector('#loginTable2')
    },
        {
            button: document.querySelector('#loginLink3'),
            table: document.querySelector('#loginTable3')
        }
    ]
    
    function toggleTable(button) {
        for(var tableItem of tableList) {
           if(tableItem.button == button)
               tableItem.table.style.display = 'block';
           else tableItem.table.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    tableList.forEach(tableItem => {
      tableItem.button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        toggleTable(this);
      });
    });
```

```html
<a id="loginLink1" href="#">Login1</a>
<a id="loginLink2" href="#">Login2</a>
<a id="loginLink3" href="#">Login3</a>
<table id="loginTable1" width="1139" height="327" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Individuals<span style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;"></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent A</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/1.png" width="750" height="33" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent B</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent C</span> </th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/2.png" width="750" height="33" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent D</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent E</span></span>
      </th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/css/images/slider-1/3.png" width="750" height="33" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Telephony Agent F</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="loginTable2" width="1139" height="327" border="0" style="display: none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Branches<span style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;"></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Sandton City Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/1@2x.jpg" width="750" height="33" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: ##005c61; font-size: 12px;">Mall of Africa Branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Bank City Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/2@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">West Street branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Springs Mall Branch</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/3@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="text-decoration-color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Westgate Mall Branch</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="loginTable3" width="1139" height="327" border="0" style="display: none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th height="53" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#4CB7B7" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;" scope="row">Leading Region</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td width="84" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="309" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="364" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="56" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Inland</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/region/1@2x.jpg" width="750" height="34" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: ##005c61; font-size: 12px;">Eastern Cape</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="61" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: ##005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Gauteng North</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/region/2@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Gauteng South</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="59" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;" scope="row"><span style="color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Soshanguve</span></th>
      <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="assets/img/sliders/branch/3@2x.jpg" width="750" height="35" alt="" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: open-sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; color: #005c61;"><span style="text-decoration-color: #005c61; font-size: 12px;">Ga-Rankuwa</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```